# Repeat android animation

Tags: android, android-animation

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.vitesse);

    gpsManager = new GPSManager();

    gpsManager.startListening(getApplicationContext());
    gpsManager.setGPSCallback(this);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "font/DS-DIGI.TTF");
     TextView  loding =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.info_message);
            loding.setTypeface(tf);
            AlphaAnimation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f , 1.0f ) ; 
            AlphaAnimation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation( 1.0f , 0.0f ) ; 
            loding.startAnimation(fadeIn);
            loding.startAnimation(fadeOut);
            fadeIn.setDuration(500);
            fadeOut.setDuration(1200);
            fadeOut.setStartOffset(1200+fadeIn.getStartOffset()+1200);     
            measurement_index = AppSettings.getMeasureUnit(this);
}
```

I want to repeat this of textview loding animation until gotting an inforamtion from GPS

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Like [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#INFINITE).

```
animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
```

Comment: You can also define it in the XML, like:

android:repeatCount = "infinite"

Answer (score 36):

Android gives you elegant mechanisms to represent the loading process. You could use an indeterminate `ProgressBar`, or an `ImageView` with a scale/alpha animation, instead of animating the `TextView` itself.

Maybe you might find this animation useful, for animating alpha and scale at the same time. Vary the parameters for your preference:

`file res/anim/alpha_scale_animation.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<scale
    android:fromXScale="0.7"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.7"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%p"
    android:pivotY="50%p"
    android:duration="4000"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    />

<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    />
</set>
```

then to launch it in your code:

```
Animation connectingAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.alpha_scale_animation);
myView.startAnimation(connectingAnimation);
```

And to stop it:

```
myView.clearAnimation();
connectingAnimation.cancel();
connectingAnimation.reset();
```

You can also use libraries like [ProgressButtonView](https://github.com/voghDev/ProgressButtonView) to have both user interaction and loading process supported in the same widget.

Hope that any of these solutions result useful to someone :)

Comment: The documentation for `cancel()` (I'm using _ValueAnimator_, a sub-class) states that it needs to be on the same thread as the caller.  This is rather inconvenient, but it seems to work anyway!  (For others using the ValueAnimator class, there is no `reset()`; doesn't seem to need it.)

Comment: You're right. `reset()` is not necessary and `cancel()` should be enough

Answer (score 11):

You can use these methods to control the repeat behavior:

```
fadeIn.setRepeatCount(int count) // or Animation.INFINITE

fadeIn.setRepeatMode(Animation.REPEAT) // or any other repeat mode, such as Animation.REVERSE
```

implement these listeners, if needed:

```
// anim = your animation    
anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

if you wanna stop your animation suddenly, use `yourView.clearAnimation()` I hope this helps.

Comment: [setRepeatMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setRepeatMode(int)) expects only RESTART or REVERSE. INFINITE should only be given to setRepeatCount.

Answer (score 8):

to repeat animation just add the code in  xml file which located in  anim folder file in which we create a animation object.

1. android:repeatCount="infinite"
2. android:repeatMode="restart"

Answer (score 2):

As well as other answers, but there is **a point** here

if you use a reserve animation from  `android.R.anim.` you can use this way

```
animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
```

**but** if you use your animation `(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.move_y)` so you must use this way in the XML

```
 android:repeatCount="infinite"
```

Answer (score 0):

Set repeat count to -1 then it will animate infinite

Comment: This is a valid answer, but it might be useful to include a code sample. It also doesn't necessarily follow best coding practices by using a static value, instead of referencing an official variable (such as `Animation.REPEAT`). But that doesn't make it a bad answer--welcome to the community! :)