# Infinite animation in android doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I tried to add infinite animation to my app but it doesn't work. This is animation (it zoom in and zoom out view):

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<scale
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="0.5" />

<scale
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="1000"
    android:toXScale="2"
    android:toYScale="2" />
</set>
```

I added a code like this:

```
    binding.txtHelp.setOnClickListener {
        val animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(App.context, R.anim.zoomin)
        animation.repeatCount = Animation.INFINITE
        it.startAnimation(animation)
    }
```

Or I tried to set `android:repeatCount="infinite"` on scales but the problem is that the first scale is executing the whole time, not after the second scale.

Comment: [Please look into this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52537149/9254960) it may help you

Comment: I added `android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"` but it still doesn't work

Comment: When I have a single animation not with 2 scales elements it works when I just add `android:repeatCount="infinite"`. But in animation like this in post, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I combined all answers and I ended up on doing this:

```
    <scale
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="0.5" />
```

This works fine. Just one scale with `android:repeatCount="infinite"` but also `android:repeatMode="reverse"` so the view zooms in and out smoothly

Answer (score 1):

Visit [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4480652/11002756)  Question

Put `android:repeatCount="infinite"` in Your scale not in set

Originally [Answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4844448/11002756)

Comment: I tried it but I have two scale elements so if I Put infinite to both my animation doesn't work in the proper way because the first scale should should be done after the whole animation ends not all the time.

Comment: poor question quality . attach your trial code with the error you face so other developer can solve it appropriately

Comment: I added the whole code, I don't get any errors. This animation is just executing once and I want to execute it all the time